# Screen scraping actual page not source html with R

Tags: r, screen-scraping

I am trying to screen scrape tennis results data (point by point data, not just final result) from this page using R.

http://www.scoreboard.com/au/match/wang-j-karlovic-i-2014/M1mWYtEF/#point-by-point;1

Using the regular R screen scraping functions like readlines(),htmlParseTree() etc I am able to scrape the source html for the page, but that does not contain the results data.

Is it possible to scrape all the text from the page, as if I were on the page in my browser and selected all and then copied?

Comment: ..results data?  The result of the match?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That data is loaded using AJAX from http://d.scoreboard.com/au/x/feed/d_mh_M1mWYtEF_en-au_1, so R will not be able to just load it for you. However, because both use the code `M1mWYtEF`, you can go directly to the page that has the data you want. Using Chrome's devtools, I was able to see that the page sends a header of `X-Fsign: SW9D1eZo` that will let you access that page (you get a `401 Unauthorized` error otherwise).

Here is R code for getting the html that holds the data you want from your example page:

```
library(httr)
page_code <- "M1mWYtEF"
linked_page <- paste0("http://d.scoreboard.com/au/x/feed/d_mh_", 
                      page_code, "_en-au_1")
GET(linked_page, add_headers("X-Fsign" = "SW9D1eZo"))
```

Comment: +1, I learnt how the queries are handled thanks!. The following also helped to browse the chrome console (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200329/view-ajax-response-content-in-chrome-developer-tools)

Comment: waternova, you are a legend!