# Backbone not fetching JSON from different host

Tags: javascript, php, json, rest, backbone.js

I am new to the RESTful concept, learning Backbone now and I am having some problems.

Right now I am running a single page application on http://localhost using backbone.js and the API is at http://phalconapi (another vhost).

At http://phalconapi I have this jsontest.php script returning JSON:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
echo json_encode( ['test'=>1] );
```

At http://localhost, this is my app.js enabling backbone.

```
var FlightsList = Backbone.Model.extend({
    //urlRoot: '/jsontest.php'
    urlRoot: 'http://phalconapi/jsontest.php'
});

var DashboardController = BackboneMVC.Controller.extend({
    name: 'dashboard',

    home: function() {
        var flights = new FlightsList();

        flights.fetch({
            success: function(flights) {
                alert(flights.toJSON());
                console.log(flights.toJSON());
            },
            error: function(model, xhr, options) {
                console.log('Fetch error');
            }
        });
    }
});

var router = new BackboneMVC.Router();

Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
```

So the problem is, whenever I set the `urlRoot` in backbone to `/jsontest.php` and I place that file in the same directory (in localhost), it works just fine.

But when I change it to `http://phalconapi/jsontest.php`, then it doesn't work. Using Google Chrome Developer Tools I noticed the message "This request has no response data available." and that didn't show up on the other test using `/jsontest.php` as `urlRoot`. Right there it's supposed to show `{"test":1}`.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3206882/477563

Comment: Possible CORS issue? Check your network tab in chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by setting access control headers on the api:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

It was a CORS issue. Thank you Half Crazed!

If someone's also using Phalcon, use `$response->setHeader()`.